# Understanding numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

I went through the [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) doc. I don't get the meaning of the sentence in the doc:

> The excluded argument can be used to prevent vectorizing over certain arguments. This can be useful for array-like arguments of a fixed length such as the coefficients for a polynomial as in [polyval](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval).

I found below example there (I added `print()` statement for exploring my doubt as explained below):

```
def mypolyval(p, x):
    print('Called mypolyval: ',(p,x))
    _p = list(p)
    res = _p.pop(0)
    while _p:
        res = res*x + _p.pop(0)
    return res

vpolyval = np.vectorize(mypolyval, excluded=['p'])

res2 = vpolyval(p=[1, 2, 3], x=[0, 1])

print(res2)
```

The output without `print()` was `[3,6]`. So, I felt `numpy.vectorize` evaluates `mypolyval` by calling it twice, once for each element of `x` and passing complete `p` array each time. Thats why the output contained two elements `3` and `6`. But when I debugged, it ran thrice, twice with `x=0` and once with `x=1`. To confirm my debugging observation, I added `print()` statement. This is the output, which confirms my debugging observation:

```
Called mypolyval:  ([1, 2, 3], 0)
Called mypolyval:  ([1, 2, 3], 0)
Called mypolyval:  ([1, 2, 3], 1)
[3 6]
```

So, am I incorrect to think that it should execute only twice once for `x=0` or `x=1`?

Comment: did you read about `otypes`

Comment: Congrats on using the diagnostic print.  `np.vectorize` has lots of features that give beginners problems.  In this case one of the calls is used to determine the return dtype.  Also pay attention to its performance disclaimer.  It may not be worth your time trying to master this function.

Comment: I realize `mypolyval` may be a toy example, but do you realize that `mypolyval(p,np.array([0,1]))` works.  No need for `np.vectorize`.

Comment: aah!!! so weird...